# How can I access these form values?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to create a form where I will perform an operation with the values entered by the user, but when the function runs, I get NaN return. Thank you in advance for the help.

```js
function test() {
  var age = document.getElementsByName("person_age").value;
  var weight = document.getElementsByName("person_weight").value;
  var size = document.getElementsByName("person_size").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = weight + size + age;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="person_age">
  <input type="text" name="person_size">
  <input type="text" name="person_weight">
  <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="test();">
</form>
<h3 id="result"></h3>`
```

Output:

> NaN

When I get the values from the user and run the function, I get NaN feedback. how can i solve this problem.

Comment: You need to access the values using document.getElementsByName("person_age")[0].value as getElementsByName returns the array not the object

Comment: But when I use document.getElementsByName("person_age")[0].value , it detects it as a string and prints the values side by side. It doesn't detect in integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple errors that you have to correct

**1)** When you use `getElementsByName`, It will return `NodeList` array like collection. So you have to get the element by using `index` as:

```
var age = document.getElementsByName( "person_age" )[0].value;
```

**2)** If you need `sum` of all three value then you have to convert it into `Number` type because `document.getElementsByName( "person_age" )[0]` give you value in `String` type. So you can do as:

```
+document.getElementsByName( "person_age" )[0].value
```

```js
function test() {
  var age = +document.getElementsByName("person_age")[0].value;
  var size = +document.getElementsByName("person_size")[0].value;
  var weight = +document.getElementsByName("person_weight")[0].value;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = weight + size + age;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="person_age">
  <input type="text" name="person_size">
  <input type="text" name="person_weight">
  <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="test();">
</form>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
```

Comment: Did you make up `kisi_boy` because it's nowhere in the question?

Comment: I might have copied from somewhere else. Thanks and edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Just a Suggestion: You can use [Document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) if you want to directly access the value. Just add an ID property in your element. It will return a string value, convert that to int and you're good to go.

```js
function test() {
  var age = document.getElementById("person_age").value;
  var weight = document.getElementById("person_weight").value;
  var size = document.getElementById("person_size").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseInt(weight) + parseInt(size) + parseInt(age); 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="person_age" id="person_age">
  <input type="text" name="person_size" id="person_size">
  <input type="text" name="person_weight" id="person_weight">
  <input type="button" value="calculate" onclick="test();">
</form>
<h3 id="result"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) will always return an array-like nodelist so, if you were to use it you would need to access the first index `[0]`. Instead add a class to each input and use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to target it.
2. The value of an input will always be a string (even if the input is type "number"), so you need to coerce it to a number, either by using [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or by prefixing the value with `+`.

So, in this example I've updated the HTML a little by adding classes to the inputs, and changing their type to "number", and removing the inline JS, and updated the JS so that the elements are cached outside of the function, an event listener is added to the button, and the values are correctly calculated.

```js
// Cache all the elements using querySelector to target
// the classes, and add an event listener to the button
// that calls the function when it's clicked
const ageEl = document.querySelector('.age');
const weightEl = document.querySelector('.weight');
const sizeEl = document.querySelector('.size');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', test, false);

function test() {

  // Coerce all the element values to numbers, and
  // then display the result
  const age = Number(ageEl.value);
  const weight = Number(weightEl.value);
  const size = Number(sizeEl.value);

  // Use textContent rather than innerHTML
  result.textContent = weight + size + age;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="age" class="age" />
  <input type="number" name="size" class="size" />
  <input type="number" name="weight" class="weight" />
  <button type="button">Calculate</button>
</form>

<h3 id="result"></h3>`
```